# How to write a jquery unit test using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using angular version1 and need to test some jquery on my index.html page.

I have added jquery to my karma conf but when I run this test jquery is undefined.

**Code I'm looking to test:**

```
        <!-- Is Angular supported -->  
        <script>
            if(window.angular === undefined)              
                 $(function(){$("#angularNotSupportedModal").load("/app/noAngularModal.html");});
        </script>   

        <div id="angularNotSupportedModal"></div>
```

**My test code:**

```
it('should call through $ chain', (done) => {
  var angular = window.angular;
  window.angular = undefined;

  spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'ready').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'load').and.callThrough();

  // make spy not break the chain
  var init = jQuery.prototype.init.bind(jQuery.prototype);
  spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'init').and.callFake(init);
  expect(jQuery.prototype.ready).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
  expect(jQuery.prototype.init).toHaveBeenCalledWith('#angularNotSupportedModal', undefined);
  expect(jQuery.prototype.load).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/app/noAngularModal.html');

  window.angular = angular;
  jQuery.ready.promise().done(done)
})
```

Comment: You should reset `window.angular` in a tearDown, otherwise it won't be reset if your test fails

Comment: If you want to unit test front end code, you have to start writing decoupled modules using OO so you can externalize dependencies. What you are doing is valid, but could be much easier.

Comment: Now, what is your question? Are there any errors?

Comment: I seem to get JQuery errors when I run the above test, any idea?

Comment: I get an error with this line: window.runAngularNotSupportedFunction

Comment: Juan I've removed "window.runAngularNotSupportedFunction" I dont use that. Basically, my code is called on load and I want to test it.

Could you change the code above so I can see how you'd get it working?